# Python str.format(): print character as integer without using ord()

Tags: python, string, formatting, ascii

I was wondering if you can use `str.format()` to convert a one-character `str` to its decimal representation, just like with `ord()`. So supposedly something like this:

```
>>> 'ASCII value is: {:d}'.format('a')  # doesn't work, but I want to convert 'a' to 97
>>> 'ASCII value is: 97'
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: By ``chr``, do you mean ``bytes``?

Comment: @Ch3steR that code isn't supposed to work. It's just a showcase of what I want to achieve

Comment: @AleksandrNovik Sorry, misunderstood the question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry, I thought `chr` is a separate type. Googled it. Just forget about `chr`, I meant one-character `str` only. :)

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty sure there is no way to do it.

Comment: I scanned through [format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) from the docs I did not find any specifier that does this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yeah, looks like that.
Thought interesting enough, one can do the opposite thing: print `int` as `str`:
`>>> '{:c}'.format(97)`
Prints `'a'`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. Didn't exactly go through the question. Yes @MisterMiyagi is right.